# store the id of a row on the option selected list from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm echoing a list of attributes of a row from a table into an option list for the user to pick from which later would be used to be inserted into another table. What I'm trying to do is, to store the 'id' of that row -not using the foreign key- separately, but the 'id' I keep getting is the 'id' of the last row on the list. Here is a snippet to my code:

```
        <?php
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

          $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE region = '{$thisRegion}' ");
          //$result .= " ");
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
            $selected = (isset($_POST['list']) && $_POST['list'] ==  $row['id']) ? 'selected' : '';
              echo "<option value='$row[streetAddress] $row[apt] $row[city] $row[zip] $row[_state] $row[country]' $selected >$row[city] $row[zip] $row[_state] $row[country] $row[streetAddress] $row[apt]</option>";
              $thisId= $row['id'];
              $_SESSION["thisId"] = $thisId;
          }
          ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$_SESSION['thisId']` with each iteration of your loop. Doing it this way, you will always end up with the last one.

Comment: If you want the selected ID, just use `$_SESSION["thisId"] = `$_POST['list']`

Comment: You have to wrap between `{ }` the arrays, not the single variables like `$thisRegion`. And the key of the array must be between quotes: `$row['streetAddress']`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem it's on the code

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    ...
    $thisId= $row['id'];
    $_SESSION["thisId"] = $thisId;
}
```

That code means that on each iteration, $_SESSION["thisId"] will be replaced with the id of the current row, making it so that at the end of the loop only the last row's ID will be there.

The way I think to do this would be to add the id to the option, and print the row just as display.

```
echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'> {$row['apt']} {$row['city']}... </option>";
```

Then, the receiving page could read

```
$selectedRowId = $_GET['optionKey']
```

I hope that helps, you should read more about php and forms moving forward as it will make your coding easier. Here is one basic tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Hi, I actually need the row to be displayed for the user to pick from. Displaying just the ID itself for the users would defeat the purpose of the option list to pick from as they wouldn't know which ID belongs to what row, and I wouldn't want them to actually know what the ID is for that row.

Comment: You should also look up about the option tag my friend. the syntax is <option value='toBeSend'>to be displayed</option>. As I put it on my code, that form will display the row information and send the row id on submit.

Comment: It will send the id, however, by doing that, other entities on my table would only be displayed on not sent. So, I need my ID to be stored separately - which I'm trying to do-, and I also need other entities to be sent as one variable separately, as it's shown in my code. Thank you my friend

Comment: As long as you send the ID you can retrieve the row data again by querying your database for that row ID. Otherwise you will need to use hidden input fields and javascript to do what you want, which is quite unnecessary imo.